# Convert XML to AVRO using convertRecord processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to convert below XML file to AVRO format using convertRecord processor. Here i am not able to get the values of attributes in AVRO format.

XML-

```
<book id="b002">
    <author>Brandon Sanderson</author>
    <title>Way of Kings</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>50</price>
    <pub_date>2006-12-17T09:30:47.0Z</pub_date>
    <sold>10</sold>
</book>
```

Comment: please provide the parameters of the convertRecord processor

Comment: I was able to get the attribute value by defining source as attribute in AVRO schema.
{
                "name" : "currency",
                "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
                "default" : null,
                "source" : "attribute currency"
              }

Answer (score 0):

It appears the asker already found a solution:

I was able to get the attribute value by defining source as attribute in AVRO schema. { "name" : "currency", "type" : [ "null", "string" ], "default" : null, "source" : "attribute currency" }